# Want to change pie/donut chart behavior for legend click

Tags: javascript, plotly, pie-chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkPW1.jpg)I want to change the behavior for Plotly legend click for donut/pie chart. The default single click on legend removes the parameter and adjusts the new chart accordingly.
Needed Behavior-When a user clicks on a specific legend the respective portion should be highlighted, the other portions color should change to a lighter shade of the current color and the selected one should stay as is.

I tried changing the default legendclick event listener for the donut/pie chart ,but the same still executes regardless of what I assign for the event.
Below is my Javascript function to generate the pie/donut chart

```
function createDonutGraph(response, x_label) {
    const x_axis = response?.data?.[0]?.chart_data?.x_axis || [];
    const y_axis = response?.data?.[0]?.chart_data?.y_axis || [];

    // Assuming you're using Plotly.js
    const data = [{
        values: y_axis,
        labels: x_axis,
        type: 'pie',
        hole: 0.4, // Hole to create the donut effect
    }];

    const layout = {
        title: {
            text: `Distribution by ${x_label}`,
            font: {
                size: 16,
            },
            x: 0,
        },
        // You can customize other layout options here
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('chart-div', data, layout);
    createResponsiveDonutChart(data,x_label);

}

function createResponsiveDonutChart(chartData,x_label) {
    const targetDivId = 'graph-section-id';
    const chartLayout = {
        title: {
            text: `Distribution by ${x_label}`,
            font: {
                size: 16,
            },
            x: 0,
        },
        margin: {
            l: 50,
            r: 50,
            b: 50,
            t: 50,
            pad: 4
        }
       
    };

    function plotChart() {
        const targetDiv = document.getElementById(targetDivId);
        const observer = new ResizeObserver(function() {
            Plotly.newPlot(targetDivId, chartData, chartLayout);
        });

        observer.observe(targetDiv);
    }

    plotChart();
}
```

Below is the JSON response received from an API ,I am using to plot the chart

```
{
    "message": "data_updated",
    "status": "201",
    "success": "true",
    "updated_data": {
        "x_axis": [
            "Standard Class",
            "Second Class",
            "First Class",
            "Same Day"
        ],
        "y_axis": [
            4286.0,
            1603.0,
            1364.0,
            306.0
        ]
    }
}
```